# Can we make columns headerText editable in Primefaces?

Tags: jsf, primefaces

Can we make Columns headerText of a p:datatable editable?

i want to nest a table in another table and to save the headerText in the entity of the outer datatable.

Any idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can put a whole input component in it if you use `<f:facet name="header">` instead of `headerText` attribute.

```
<p:column>
    <f:facet name="header">
        <p:inputText ... />
    </f:facet>
    ...
</p:column>
```